# Unzip a large file in Windows phone causes OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have downloaded a large zip file using background transfer service in Windows Phone applications.

When I tried to unzip the file using the following [tutorial](http://ooiks.com/blog/windows-phone/windows-phone-unzip-extract-compressed-files-for-silverlight):

```
private void LoadZipfile()
{
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    c.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(openReadCompleted);
    c.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/myZipFile.zip"));
}

private void openReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    UnZipper unzip = new UnZipper(e.Result);
    foreach (string filename in unzip.FileNamesInZip())
    {
        Stream stream = unzip.GetFileStream(filename);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(contents);
    }
}
```

But while unziping, it throws the *OutOfMemory* exception.

Please suggest to me how to resolve the issue

Comment: On a phone this could easily be an actual hardware limit. I'd suggest attempting to unzip some files of increasing size to see if there as a  point which causes the memory exception to occur.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that the problem here is these two lines

```
string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(contents);
```

These two lines try to read the entire file in a string variable and try to show it up. This is not a good practice on a phone (not even on a desktop which has huge memory and page file support).

Try reading few bytes from the stream and put it in string and show it in messagebox. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I got error in the following line                                Stream stream = unzip.GetFileStream(filename);